# How do I get my Google-service.json working with Firestore inside Google Cloud Plataform?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the google cloud platform to make my system. Inside of it has a Firestore system, that use the same API and packages that the outside (outside of the Google Cloud Platform) use.

I know that using the outside one you can generate a Json to use as a key to work with the FireStore Module inside flutter/dart. But using the inside Firestore GCP, you just can generate a GCP Key, and not a Firestore key. Even using the "firestore adm" option in the key generator.

Here the simple code that I'm using to start the Firestore thing

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

bool teste() {
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  //print(firestore.collection("users").snapshots());

  return false;
}
```

And here the bug that appears to me when I try to use the GCP key:

```
E/flutter (11150): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?
E/flutter (11150):
E/flutter (11150):     View the Android Installation documentation for more information: https://firebaseextended.github.io/flutterfire/docs/installation/android
E/flutter (11150):
E/flutter (11150): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:86:9)
E/flutter (11150): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11150): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:25)
E/flutter (11150): #2      teste (package:invideo_finder/backend/verifyFireBase.dart:7:12)
E/flutter (11150): #3      _RegisterPageState.verifyUser.<anonymous closure> (package:invideo_finder/pages/register.dart:51:11)
E/flutter (11150): #4      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1244:30)
E/flutter (11150): #5      _RegisterPageState.verifyUser (package:invideo_finder/pages/register.dart:34:5)
E/flutter (11150): #6      _RegisterPageState.onPressButton (package:invideo_finder/pages/register.dart:69:27)
E/flutter (11150): #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (11150): #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (11150): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (11150): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (11150): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (11150): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7)
E/flutter (11150): #13     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (11150): #14     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (11150): #15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (11150): #16     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (11150): #17     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (11150): #18     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (11150): #19     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
E/flutter (11150): #20     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (11150): #21     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (11150): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (11150): #23     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (11150): #24     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (11150): #25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (11150): #26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (11150): #27     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
```

Some one can, please help me with it? I don't have any idea of what to do.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is here.  What do you mean by "inside Firestore GCP"?  How is that different than working with Firestore normally in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

The `google-services.json` contains the credentials in order for yur app to access the services in GCP therefore You can use a `credentials.json`  that can be generated for a service account. following the [next steps](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts):

- Create a service account

  - Go the the [Service Account Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)
  - Click on **Create Service Account**
  - Enter its name, and description
  - Click on **Create**
  - Select the roles you need to access the services you are going to use from your app
  - Click on **Continue**
  - Click on Done
- Click on the Service account you are using
- Click on **Add Key**
- Select JSON
- Click on **Create**

These steps will allow you to create a service accound and download its `Credentials.json` file.

In case you want to use the `google-services.json` this file is the one generated by Firebase, and can be downloaded from the firebase console after registering an app there.

Consider that when you have a GCP project you can enable firebase on it by accessing the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and accessing to your project. and all the resources compatible with both platforms will be shared, including Firestore

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware that you can actually access your project google-services.json file in your Firebase console. This is the correct way of using Firebase services.

You can get the file in your project settings on Firebase Console.

Comment: i'm now using Firebase, I'm using Google cloud Platform Firestore. Exist some command to ask for this Json(in the console)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you have an firestore in Google cloud plataform you have one in FireBase plataform too, I didn't knew this